# Prevent the player from wearing specific player heads

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am in Java 1.14.4 and I'm trying to use player heads as a way to make custom items.  However, the problem with this is that the player can wear these heads if they put it on their head slot.

I tried some simple commands to try and remove the heads like this:

```
execute as @a[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:103b,Count:1b,id:"minecraft:player_head"}]}] run give @s player_head
execute as @a[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:103b,Count:1b,id:"minecraft:player_head"}]}] run replaceitem entity @s armor.head air
```

However, the first problem with this is that if the player "shift-clicks" the player head-on, they can actually duplicate it.  Another issue is that it is extremely inconsistent.  Sometimes the commands will work as intended, other times it will just not occur, and the head will remain on the player.

Comment: "I'm trying to use player heads as a way to make custom items." Why? You're apparently having problems with it. Why does it need to be a player head?

Comment: @FabianRöling It doesn't have to be player heads, but I really don't want to use a resource pack for this project, and items like a first aid kit can't be depicted with the normal Minecraft items.

Comment: Your commands work fine for me. No shift-clicking bug. Did you test it in Creative or Survival? The Creative inventory has a bunch of bugs, maybe this is one of them.

Comment: but with these commands you will have the problem, that the new playerhead won't have the nbt-data...

Comment: @commanderguy These commands were just examples of what I was doing.  In the actual commands, I have the NBT data for the player heads, but it made the commands so long I didn't think it was necessary to include.

Comment: @FabianRöling Yeah, it seems when I go into adventure mode it's fine.  I was always testing in creative.

Comment: @Hydra how do you want to clone the nbt data, you can't merge the entitydata of a player...  maybe you can post the actual commands, that we can see, how you want to do this.

Comment: @Hydra In Creative Mode it can also work, but you mustn't execute the command every tick, cause then it spawns a phantom-item, you should execute the command every second tick, then it should work.

Comment: @commanderguy The actual commands are just long NBT data for the player heads. I'm hardcoding this for each player head I'm using as a custom item.  And I'm not sure what you mean by having the command execute every second tick?

Comment: activate the command only ten times per second, not twenty times as it would be in an always active repeating commandblock. there are several ways to do this, like an extra scoreboard which gets increased every tick, and every second tick the command would be executed.

Comment: in case this question isn't already answered, wouldn't it be simpler for your medpacks to just be potions that give instant HP etc.? this would save a lot of command manipulation and bugs.

Comment: @EarthToAccess This question has been resolved, even though no one has answered. It turns out that in survival mode there is no issue. Creative mode has a lot of bugs related to the inventory. As to using an instant health potion, that is already an alternative healing item. This first-aid kit has different mechanics than simply clicking that I would like to have.